# Deleting Android App

Tags: android

I have a couple people using an Android app that I made, report: "It won't let me delete the app"

Is that possible? I didn't think that you could prevent the app from being deleted.
I use this in my manifest. Could that be causing some people's problems?

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

EDIT:

I should clarify. I have a contact form in my app for people to report bugs & send comments. In the last 3 days I had two different people tell me they couldn't delete the app from their phone. So, it's literally a few of my users that are telling me this.

I'm not sure whether they just don't understand how to uninstall an app or if there might possibly be something in my code that's causing a problem.

Comment: can you write the link to that report?

Comment: I should clarify. I have a contact form in my app for people to report bugs & send comments.

Answer (score 2):

If the application has the **Device Admin Right Enabled** then the application can not be uninstalled. And it also not shows such message. There may be other cases, but if is to then you can check this by `Settings -> Location and Security -> Select Device Administrator` and see if there in the list the application appears. If it so then uncheck the application to disable the  DeviceAdmin right. Now you can uninstall the application successfully.